# Cargo: How to include the entire directory or file in feature flags?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

I'm working on a Rust project. I'm using Cargo feature flags for conditional compilation of the some code. There are cases where I have to include the **entire** file in the feature flags so doing so adding `#[cfg(feature="my-flag")]` over every function & `use` statement doesn't make much sense.

So to include the entire file in the feature flag I'm thinking to surround all the contents in the file a block & add the feature flag for the block.

```
#[cfg(feature="my-flag")]
{
  use crate::access_control::{func1, func2};
  use crate::models;
  ...

  #[derive(Debug)]
  pub enum MyEnum{..}
  
  #[derive(Clone)]
  pub Struct MyStruct{..}

  pub fn my_func() {...}
  fn my_func_internal() {...}
  ...
}
```

But I'm getting the error `Syntax Error: expected an item after attributes`

Also, there are also some cases where I want the entire directory to be included the feature flags. How should I go about it? Doing the adding feature flags for every file is one way. Does a better way exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in [@MarcusDunn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75230468/5397009), the proper solution is to apply the attribute to the `mod` declaration:

```
// This conditionally includes a module which implements WEBP support.
#[cfg(feature = "webp")]
pub mod webp;
```

However for the sake of completeness, I would point out that attributes can be applied to the item they're in instead of being applied to the following item. These are called ["inner attributes"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) and are specified by adding a `!` after the `#`:

```
#![cfg(feature="my-flag")] // Applies to the whole file

use crate::access_control::{func1, func2};
use crate::models;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyEnum {}
  
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {}

pub fn my_func() {}
fn my_func_internal() {}
```

Comment: I think both are required, removing the module `webp` from all the places that includes it say lib.rs and main.rs. And then in the webp.rs file adding the inner attribute for the entire file? I suspect that if the later isn't done then webp.rs will still be compiled?

Comment: If you do it on the `pub mod webp` then you need to do it for all the `use webp` instances too, but you don't need to do it inside the `webp.rs` file itself. If you do it inside the file, then you don't need to do it for the `pub mod webp;`, nor the `use webp;` (but you still need it for targeted imports, e.g. `use webp::MyEnum` and actual uses).

Comment: The above comment makes it clear

Comment: If I have nested directories: directory `a` has a directory `b` which has files `c` & `d`. Then will `c` & `d` be conditionally compiled if I only add the feature flag for `pub mod a`? Or should I add inner attribute for files `c` & `d`. Basically how does **nesting** work for feature flags?

Comment: Once you disable `a`, you disable everything inside `a` at the same time: types, functions, constants, macros and submodules. So you only need to feature-gate `a` itself.

Comment: What about **multi-line** flags? This can be done with a `#[cfg(feature = "webp")]` on each prior line. Is there a better way? Is the only other is [cfg-if](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/latest/cfg_if/)? I think this will make your answer a comprehensive reference on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

From https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html

```
// This conditionally includes a module which implements WEBP support.
#[cfg(feature = "webp")]
pub mod webp;
```

This could be an entire directory - or a single file, depends how you structure your modules.

Comment: I think both are required, removing the module webp from all the places that includes it say lib.rs and main.rs. And then in the webp.rs file adding the inner attribute for the entire file? I suspect that if the later isn't done then webp.rs will still be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional compilation on modules. Perhaps something like this would work for your use case:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "feat")]
use feat::S;
#[cfg(not(feature = "feat"))]
use no_feat::S;

mod feat {
    pub const S: &str = "feat";
}

mod no_feat {
    pub const S: &str = "no_feat";
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", S);
}
```

Running with `cargo run`:

```
no_feat
```

Running with `cargo run --features feat`:

```
feat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`cfg-if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if) crate:

```rust
cfg_if::cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "my-flag")] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be used for **multi-line** flags? This can be done with a #[cfg(feature = "my-flag")] on each prior line. Is there a better way?

Comment: @NewToCode What do you mean by "multi-line flags"?

Comment: Say I have multiple consecutive lines in a **function** that should be executed only when the feature flag is set. In that case I use `#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]` on each prior line to conditionally compile it. Is there a better way?

Comment: @NewToCode You can wrap them all in a `cfg_if!`. However, if those are statements inside a function, you can also wrap them in a block in `#[cfg]` it.